# Japanese term or phrase: 有価証券

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage

Full text: その他有価証券評価差額金

My issue: 有価証券. Is it "Securities" or "Marketable Securities"?

My understanding: Valuation difference on other marketable securities

Answer (score 1):

有価証券　= marketable securities (Agreed). However, その他有価証券 must be translated as available-for-sale securities. It is a stand-alone asset account that is subject to tighter valuation rules than investment securities or held-to-maturity securities.